# How Can I extract the image path from <ri:attachment ri:filename="stories-img-05.png" />

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Here is the original code where I am extracted the data using Simple HTML Dom:

```
<div class="content-wrapper"><p><ac:image ac:height="250"><ri:attachment ri:filename="stories-img-05.png" /></ac:image></p></div>
```

Here is the code which i am using :

```
$html->find('div[class=content-wrapper] p ac:image ', 0)->innertext;
```

How can I get Image Path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple use this code:

```
    $img=array();
    foreach($html->find('div.content-wrapper ri:attachment[ri:filename]') as $article) {
        array_push($img, $article->attr['ri:filename']);
    }
    print_r($img);
```

For single use this:

```
$html->find('div.content-wrapper ri:attachment[ri:filename]')[0]->attr['ri:filename']
```

Comment: @NigSysTechnologies

$re = '/ri:filename="(.*)".*\/>/';
  $str = '<div class="content-wrapper"><p><ac:image ac:height="250"><ri:attachment ri:filename="stories-img-05.png" /></ac:image></p></div>';

  preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

  echo $matches[0][1];

Comment: Good Work Pradeep Thanks

Comment: @NigSysTechnologies If this answer solved your problem please accept it.